# D3 SVG issue in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, svg

I am having some trouble in displaying a scrolling legends using D3 and SVG. My legends vary based on data and can be of any range. from 1 to 150

here's a simple working fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/bikrantsharma/eqnnd84v/

On Chrome: everything works fine it scrolls well But in IE the container displays of a smaller height and all the legends are displaying real small and with no scroll coz the max-height is never hit.

I have read somewhere that IE does not determine the SVG height correctly so we have to use relative positioning and provide initial height.

I have tried applying relative and absolute positioning as

```
.legend-main-div{
height:0;
padding:40%;
position:relative;
}

.SVGClass{
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
     position:absolute;
}
```

where SVGClass is applied to the svg element. This displays the legends correctly but now i loose the scrolling functionality.

Is there a way to get scrolling legends working in both chrome and IE?

For some reason in the fiddle all the items are not getting displayed in my scrolling window but in my actual code it is working fine.

Comment: Does anything work on IE? Joking aside, I'm getting the exact same result (Chrome and IE 11).

Comment: It does suck big time on various fronts..

Comment: strange!! do you know why it is showing only few check boxes in fiddle and not all of them?

Comment: i might be missing something..in the actual application the it shows other items in the scrolling panel when max-height is hit on the container that holds svg..ok in short what can i do to show all the items and scroll in my fiddle??

Comment: That's a different problem, I advise you to edit this question or, even better, post a *new* question, explaining your issue.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43626212/svg-d3-scrolling-with-max-height

Comment: you can see the issue in IE if you run the https://jsfiddle.net/ahafvqzw/ with height '100%'

Answer (score 1):

Well thanks Gerado for the suggestion on the other question..

on Chrome - Setting height to '100%' was not affecting the viewport height which was set to the responsive div height.

Whereas on IE - Setting the height to 100% was causing the viewport to get the initial height instead of what was set inside the view port.

Setting the height of SVG to responsiveDiv height instead of 100% actually resolved the issue. Updated the fiddle.

if someone wants to see how it looks in IE change the legendSVG height to '100%'

Please let me know of any comment