# SVG D3 Scrolling with max height

Tags: jquery, d3.js, svg

I have a very simple ui with bunch of rect added on a scrolling div container with max-height.

https://jsfiddle.net/bikrantsharma/eqnnd84v/

```
.legend-main-div {
  padding: 2%;
  height: 150px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

it is only showing only few svg items. how can i show all the items in the container with the same max-height?

Comment: oh i see..yeah that what i wanted..i set the height to 100% which was the default.. i guess i am good with this one..Thanks

Comment: I just made another fiddle, which I believe will suit you better, check the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct in setting the height using a percentage unit. However, the view box is wrongly named: it is `viewBox`, not `viewbox`.

```
.attr('viewBox', '0 0 500 ' + responsiveDivHeight + '')
```

Here is your updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ahafvqzw/

Comment: thanks now you can see the issue in IE on my other question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43625690/d3-svg-issue-in-internet-explorer if you run the fiddle in IE with height '100%' it will show you the issue. But i am going to replace the height with responsiveDivHeight which will work in my case.